# Source of "not specified" warnings in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

From time to time I like to check the Warnings tab after I've built in VS to see if there's anything I ought to clean up. Normally there's nothing untoward in there. Having just done so, however, I got a whole bunch of these:

[image]

There are similar ones for 'Author', which insert my name by default:

> Author was not specified. Using 'my.name'.    EXEC

There seems to be a pair of these for each project in the solution.

Googling for this I've found a bunch of references to people encountering the problem when building NuGet packages. But this is a ClickOnce WPF application. I have no idea what someone on the team might have done to cause this, and neither does anyone else.

What's going on here, and how can I remove the warnings?

Comment: Title says 2015, tag says 2013. Which is it?

Comment: @MSalters My fault, sorry. It's 2013.